# Como fazer para que um grupo de parâmetros seja requerido se pelo menos um deles for informado?

Tags: python

Em Python temos os valores default, que são opcionais quando chamamos uma função.
Queria saber se tem algum jeito de fazer com que um grupo de valores sejam opcionais, tipo ou se passa todos aqueles valores ou nenhum.

```
def func(nome=None, cpf=None):
    pass
```

Caso se passe apenas o nome ou o cpf daria um erro, só funcionaria se passar os dois ou nenhum. Não sei se minha pergunta fez sentido, espero que sim.

Answer (score 3):

> **TL;DR**
>   Para responder especificamente à pergunta, vá direto ao tópico **"Respondendo especificamente a pergunta."**

Em Python podemos chamar funções, enviando argumentos de forma "posicional" e/ou  "nomeada", para entender isso vejamos uma função que recebe 3 argumentos e apenas os devolve em uma tupla:

```
def f1(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    return (arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Como esses argumentos não tem valores atribuídos (valores default), são considerados argumentos obrigatórios, sendo assim, para chamar essa função temos que passar os 3 argumentos obrigatoriamente, mas temos duas formas de fazer isso:

Chamando os argumentos de forma posicional:

```
>>> f1(1,2,3)
(1,2,3)
```

Ou de forma nomeada:

```
>>> f1(arg2=2, arg1=3, arg3=1)
(3,2,1)
```

Note que apesar da obrigatoriedade do envio dos 3 argumentos a ordem dos argumentos não precisa ser a mesma quando chamamos a função com a forma nomeada.

Podemos também fazer um *mix*, chamando parte de forma posicional e parte de forma nomeada, desde que a forma posicional anteceda a forma posicionada:

```
# Ok
>>> f1(1, 2, arg3=99) 
(1, 2, 99)

# Error
>>> f1(1, arg2=2, 3)
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

É importante observar que temos que enviar sempre os 3 argumentos, sem repeti-los, chamadas como as exemplificadas abaixo levantarão exceção de erros:

```
>>> f1(1, 2, arg1=10)
TypeError: f1() got multiple values for argument 'arg1'

>>> f1(arg1=1, arg3=3)
f1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg2'

>>> f1(1,2)
TypeError: f1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg3'
```

**Chamar as funções enviando argumentos de forma posicional ou nomeada, qual é melhor?**

A maioria dos programadores utiliza, na maior parte do tempo, a forma posicional, mas a forma nomeada torna as chamadas às funções mais claras, flexíveis e explícitas, mais de acordo com o [zen do Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), vejamos esse código:

```
def save_txt(out_file, contents):
    with open(out_file,'w+') as f:
        for line in contents:
             f.write(line)
```

Essa função recebe como parâmetro `out_file` e `contents` pega as linhas de texto e grava no arquivo de saída, quais das chamadas abaixo ficam mais claras e flexíveis?

```
lines = '''
        Por que usar argumentos nomeados?
        Porque é mais claro e explícito
        '''
file_name = 'lines.txt' 

# Chamada com argumentos de forma posicional
save_txt(file_name, lines)

# Chamadas com argumentos na forma nomeada:
save_txt(out_file=file_name, contents=lines)

# Segunda opcao para chamada nomeada 
save_txt(contents=lines, out_file=file_name)
```

**Argumentos "default":**

Python também permite que os argumentos de uma função tenham valores atribuídos por omissão (Default), esses valores são atribuídos na definição da função:

```
def f1(arg1, arg2, arg3=99):
    return (arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Agora é obrigatório enviar os 2 primeiros parâmetros na chamada à função, mas o ultimo é opcional, a chamada requer as mesmas regras para as chamadas anteriores:

Válidas:

```
>>> f1(1,2)
(1, 2, 99)

>>> f1(1,2,arg3=88)
(1, 2, 88)

>>> f1(arg3=3, arg2=2, arg1=1) 
(1, 2, 3)
```

Inválidas:

```
>>> f1(arg3=77,1,2)
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

>>> f1(arg1=1,2,3)
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

**Número arbitrário de argumentos, seguido da obrigação de argumentos nomeados:**

Pode-se também definir uma função que recebe um número variável de argumentos seguido de argumentos obrigatoriamente nomeados, usando o operador *:

```
def f2(*args, default=99):
    return (args, default)
```

Nesse exemplo os primeiros argumentos (obrigatoriamente posicionais), não importa quantos sejam, serão recebidos na variável `args` que é do tipo `tuple`, note que a função exemplo tem como retorno uma tupla, então ao chama-la teremos como retorno uma tupla que contem a tupla `args` e o valor da variável `default`, vejamos alguns exemplos:

```
>>> f2(1,2,3)
((1, 2, 3), 99)

>>> f2(1,2,3,4,5,6,'teste',[1,2,3]) 
((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'teste', [1, 2, 3]), 99)

>>> f2(1,2,default=3)
((1, 2), 3)
```

**Somente argumentos nomeados, obrigatoriamente:**

Para que a função aceite somente argumentos nomeados, de forma obrigatória, sem a necessidade de aceitar um número arbitrário de argumentos posicionais através do operador *, é só utilizar esse mesmo operador, sem nada na sua frente:

```
def f3(*, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    return(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Veja que agora é mandatório que a chamada seja feita através da forma de argumentos nomeados e obrigatoriamente enviando todos eles, embora ainda possamos variar a ordem dos argumentos, assim temos como chamadas válidas:

```
>>> f3(arg3=1,arg2=2,arg1=3)
(3, 2, 1)

>>> f3(arg1=3,arg2=2,arg3=1)
(3, 2, 1)
```

Mas as chamadas abaixo são inválidas:

```
>>> f3(1, 2, 3)
f3() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given

>>> f3(arg1=1, arg2=2)
TypeError: f3() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'arg3'
```

**Argumentos nomeados, incluindo defaults:**

também é permitido mixar a obrigatoriedade de argumentos nomeados com argumentos *defaults*, dessa forma a última chamada acima não produziria erro, para isso a função teria que ser definida como abaixo:

```
def f3(*, arg1, arg2, arg3=99):
    return(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

O asterisco pode ser posicionado em qualquer lugar, por exemplo poderia-se se definir a função com apenas o primeiro parâmetro sendo posicional e os outros dois sendo nomeados obrigatórios, assim:

```
def f4(arg1, *, arg2,  arg3):
    return(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Nesse caso todos os argumentos seriam obrigatórios, sendo que os 2 últimos teriam que ser chamados, obrigatoriamente de forma nomeada, dessa forma teríamos como chamada inválida, por exemplo:

```
>>> f4(1, arg3=3)
f4() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'arg2'
```

Para que essa última chamada fosse válida, teríamos que ter definido a função da seguinte forma:

```
def f4(arg1, *, arg2=2,  arg3):
    return(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

**Argumentos nomeados de forma arbitrária**

Com o Python é possível, também, que uma função receba um número arbitrário de argumentos nomeados, vamos usar como exemplo a função `media_curso()` de uma escola de cursos livres que recebe como parâmetro, o nome do curso e os nomes e notas dos alunos, para calcular a média aritmética da classe.

```
def media_curso(curso, **notas):
    return sum(list(notas.values()))/len(notas)
```

Vamos chamar a função para a turma de 4 alunos do curso de Python:

```
>>> media_curso('python', john=7, Doe=9, Foo=5, Bar=6)
6.75
```

Digamos que uma aluna ingresse atrasada no curso e no próximo mês a função teria que ser chamada incluindo a nota dela, então a chamada seria:

```
>>>> media_curso('python', john=9, Doe=6, Foo=8, Bar=5, Lena=9 )
7.4
```

O que os dois asteriscos (**) fazem é pegar todos os argumentos nomeados que foram enviados em sequencia, empacotar em um dicionário e atribuir ao argumento à sua frente (no caso `notas`), uma outra forma de chamar a função seria enviando um dicionário já "resolvido" ou "desempacotado", assim:

```
>>> d = {'john': 9, 'Doe': 6, 'Foo': 8, 'Bar': 5, 'Lena': 9}
>>> media_curso('python', **d )  
7.4
```

**Tudo misturado:**

Como visto, podemos tanto passar como receber números arbitrários de argumentos, de forma nomeada ou não. É por isso que frequentemente vimos chamadas do tipo abaixo, principalmente no uso de herança, muito comum em *frameworks* como o Django.

```
def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something
    # ...
    super().some_method(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note que a convenção `kwargs` é para denotar argumentos enviados através de "key/Value". Essa é uma pratica comum quando se sobrepõe métodos de *frameworks* em que se deseja alterar o acessar parâmetros e então chamar o método "pai" na chamada `super()`.

## Respondendo especificamente a pergunta:

Depois da edição do título da pergunta notei que **não** deixei, de forma explícita, uma forma de atende-la especificamente, então elaborei, baseado no exposto acima, a seguinte solução:

```
def f(**args):
    if len(args)>0:
        if ['nome', 'cpf'] != list(args):
            return 'Erro' # Ou levante uma exceção aqui
    # Faça o que for necessário 
    return 'Ok'
```

Testando:

```
# Sem nenhum argumento:
f()
'Ok'

# Somente com um argumento
f(nome='Foo') 
'Erro'

# Com dois argumentos, sendo um com o nome errado
f(nome='Foo', idade=21) 
'Erro'

# Com os dois argumentos exigidos
f(nome='Foo', cpf=1234) 
'Ok'
```

Veja que com essa solução, os dois argumentos são obrigatórios se um deles for entregue, ou seja, ou você envia os dois ou não envia nada. Mas você pode colocar na frente um parâmetro obrigatório, por exemplo:

```
def f(cidade, **args):
    if len(args)>0:
        if ['nome', 'cpf'] != list(args):
           return 'Erro' # Ou levante uma exceção aqui
    # Faça o que for necessário 
    return cidade
```

Agora você não consegue mais chamar se não enviar pelo menos o argumento cidade, embora as condições anteriores para `nome` e `cpf` continuem válidas.

Comment: Eu recomendaria um livro em que essa resposta fosse um dos capítulos!  :-)
Mas acho que ela  aborda de forma direta apenas metade do problema da  pergunta feita: como obrigar todos os argumentos. Mas não aborda "como permitir nenhum agumento" - claro que entendendo até aqui, a pessoa pode construir uma aplicação bem sólida. (eu mesmo, vendo todas as possiblidades descritas assim estou imaginando se não há uma forma mais simples do que os decoradores que sugeri)

Comment: @jsbueno, Depois da edição do título pelo  Anderson, tive um outro entendimento da pergunta, então baseado no que ja tinha escrito, elaborei uma abordagem para atender, acredito com um pouco mais de tempo poderia ficar melhor.

Answer (score 3):

Claro que a linguagem não tem como trazer prontos todos os usos imaginados possíveis - seja para lista de parâmetros, seja pra outras coisas.

Mas ela inclui mecanismos o suficiente para você poder implementar isso - 
no caso, uma boa forma é fazer uso de decoradores! Decoradores são uma sintaxe para funções que modificam outras funções.

Esta resposta usa aspectos bastante avançados da linguagem - não tem problema se apesar de entender os conceitos não der pra entender todo o código agora - 
os exemplos abaixo usam conceitos e mecanismos sólidos o suficiente da linguagem  para serem incorporados num projeto de produção (isso é: não dependem de detalhes de implementação, ou funcionalidades não documentadas).

## Decorator que checa os parâmetros:

Então no caso, você pega os controles que, sem esse mecanismo, teriam que ficar em código normal, dentro da função - um "if" para checar se os valores foram passados, por exemplo, e move essa lógica para o decorador.

Isso é tranquilo. Outra coisa que precisamos é fazer isso funcionar pra funções genéricas: isso é, o decorador não vai saber se a função em que ele vai ser aplicado vai ter 1, 2 ou 10 parâmetros opcionais.

O módulo `inspect` tem funções que permitem checar isso - e aí podemos levantar um TypeError com a mensagem apropriada (ou retornar um valor de erro fixo, se você preferir).

No caso, o módulo `inspect` sim, tem classes e utilitários para lidar com todas as formas possíveis de parâmetros - inclusive anotações, listas de argumentos em ordem, parâmetros passados como dicionários, etc...isso faz com que seu uso seja um pouco complicado -

Para o caso em questão, são alguns passos: Usar `inspect.signature` para extrair a assinatura da função, no objeto retornado, (que é uma de classe `Signature` do módulo inspect), chamamos o método `bind` para aplicar os parâmetros passados, e no objeto retornado por isso chamamos o método `apply_defaults` e em seguida olhamos se, uma vez aplicados os parâmetros, sobrou algum dos valores padrão que você determinou = para isso comparamos os argumentos que foram vinculados com o que a `Signature` tem em seu atributo `Parameters`.

Soa complicado, mas é preciso fazer uma vez só - e você pode manter num módulo `utils.py` no seu projeto:

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect

def all_or_nothing(func):
    signature = inspect.signature(func)

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        bound_args = signature.bind(*args, **kw)
        bound_args.apply_defaults()

        all_ = True
        any_ = False
        for parameter, argument in zip(signature.parameters.values(), bound_args.arguments.values()):
            if parameter.default == argument:
                all_ = False
            else:
                any_ = True
        if any_ and not all_:
            raise TypeError(f"Either pass all optional arguments or no argument in call to {func.__name__}")
        return func(*args, **kw)

    return wrapper
```

(Seria possível fazer um decorador mais simples, sem usar o módulo "inspect", baseado apenas no número de argumentos passados - mas ele não teria vantagens sobre esse a não ser não exigir que quem escreva o decorador em si saiba usar as funcionalidades do módulo).

Funcionando:

```
In [137]: @all_or_nothing
     ...: def func(nome="", cpf=None):
     ...:     pass
     ...: 
     ...: 

In [138]: func("alo", 123)

In [139]: func()

In [140]: func("alo")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
(...)
TypeError: Either pass all optional arguments or no argument in call to func
```

## Usando Polimorfismo

Uma outra abordagem, também com decoradores, permite emular o polimorfismo - uma caracteristica que existe em linguagens estaticamente tipadas como Java e C++ - nesse caso, você cria funções com o mesmo nome, mas com lista de parâmetros distintas, e o mecanismo de decoradores despacha a chamada para a função apropriada de acordo com os parâmetros passados.  (O mesmo mecanismo do Python também tem que dar um jeito decoradas terem  o mesmo nome).

A própria linguagem Python já tem um decorador especial que faz algo parecido, mas apenas baseada no tipo do primeiro parâmetro - o `functools.singledispatch` - mas ele não faz o despacho entre números de parâmetros diferentes (e nem permite que as funções decoradas tenham o mesmo nome). Então basicamente esse mecanismo teria que ser recriado - isso, como o anterior, apesar de complexo, não é extenso, e pode ser feito uma única vez:

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect

def polymorph(original_func):
    registry = {}
    original_signature = inspect.signature(original_func)
    def register(func):
        registry[tuple(inspect.signature(func).parameters.keys())] = func
        return wrapper

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        arg_names = tuple(original_signature.bind(*args, **kw).arguments.keys())
        try:
            dispatchee = registry[arg_names]
        except KeyError:
            raise TypeError(f"No registered version of {func.__name__} found requiring parameters {arg_names}")
        return dispatchee(*args, **kw)

    register(original_func)
    wrapper.register = register
    wrapper.registry = registry
    return wrapper
```

E isso funcionando:

```
In [184]: @polymorph
     ...: def func(nome="", cpf=123):
     ...:     print(nome, cpf)
     ...: 
     ...:     
     ...:     
     ...:     
     ...:         

In [185]: @func.register
     ...: def func():
     ...:     print("no parameters")
     ...:         
     ...:         

In [186]: func()
no parameters

In [187]: func("alo", 123)
alo 123

In [188]: func("alo")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
(...)
TypeError: No registered version of func found requiring parameters ('nome',)
```

Note que não seria difícil estender esse mecanismo para atuar verificar também os tipos dos parâmetros dados por anotações - e isso possibilitaria "polimorfismo completo" - como existe em linguagens como Java ou C++ em pouco mais de 20 linhas de código

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, leia as respostas:

- [Usando decoradores, por jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372134/5878)
- [Aula de parâmetros, por Sidon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372128/5878)

Mas uma solução específica para o seu problema - isto é, algo que não seja genérico e independente da função - é validar manualmente as condições. Possuindo dois parâmetros que, por padrão, são `None`, você pode verificar se ambos são `None` ou se ambos são diferente de `None`. Se apenas um deles ser `None` significa que nem todos os parâmetros foram informados.

O operador lógico XOR resolve bem o problema:

```
def func(nome=None, cpf=None):
    if ((nome is None) ^ (cpf is None)):
        raise ValueError('Nem todos os parâmetros foram informados')
    print('Ok')
```

Assim:

```
>>> func()
'Ok'

>>> func('Anderson', 123)
'Ok'

>>> func('Anderson')
ValueError: Nem todos os parâmetros foram informados

>>> func(cpf=123)
ValueError: Nem todos os parâmetros foram informados
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, o que tu quer é obrigar a passagem dos dois valores ou não passar nenhum, o meio termo não te interessa, é isso?

Em algumas linguagens a sobrescrita de métodos se da por criar um novo com o mesmo nome, porem com outros parâmetros e assim uma outra lógica, em python isso não ocorre, nele tu tem este recurso de definir um valor default.

Para este teu caso, o melhor a fazer é criar uma verificação interna, se ambos os campos foram devidamente preenchidos ou nenhum, então lança um retorno, caso contrario lança outro retorno.